# jquery slide out from record

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, slider

I am looking for some advice on an idea which i am unsure if i can do it or not...

i am loading records out of a database and listing them in individual divs and adding an id number from the databse to the divs,the divs are about 100px wide and right across the screen..

i am wondering if i can use some kinda of plugin by jquery so that if i click on the record a tab would slide out from the right hand side with more data on that individual record from the database.. and then i could close it and it would side back so i can only see the records again..

i have had a bit of a look at the jquery ui page with all the demos but i didnt really find anything...

any help or pointers would be great.. even if u know of something simllar ill be happy to look into it...

thanks in advance for any help

Comment: you don't really need a plugin to do this, just simple jquery/html knowledge. I'll get back to you with a fiddle. Stay tuned! :)

Comment: answer is below. Shortcut; here's the fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/dUm2j/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so here's my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dUm2j/2/)

**HTML** (standard containers, etc)

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="buttons-container"></div>
    <div id="record">
        <div id="record-content"></div>            
        <a href="#" id="bt-close" onclick="closeRecord(); return false;">Close</a></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
a.bt-record {
    display:block;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background:#999999;
    color:#000;
    line-height:100px;
    text-align:center;
    float:left;
    margin:0 10px 10px 0;
    text-decoration:none;
}

a { color:#fff; }

#container {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    overflow:hidden;
    position:relative;
}

#record {
    position:absolute;
    right:-240px;
    top:100px;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    background:#000;
    padding:20px;
    color:#fff;
    z-index:1;
}
```

**Javascript**

```
//your data in a array of objects (could be something else)
var data = {
    1 : {name:'Record 1', text:'This is the text 1', options:'Anything 1'},
    2 : {name:'Record 2', text:'This is the text 2', options:'Anything 2'},
    3 : {name:'Record 3', text:'This is the text 3', options:'Anything 3'},
    4 : {name:'Record 4', text:'This is the text 4', options:'Anything 4'},
    5 : {name:'Record 5', text:'This is the text 5', options:'Anything 5'},
    6 : {name:'Record 6', text:'This is the text 6', options:'Anything 6'},
    7 : {name:'Record 7', text:'This is the text 7', options:'Anything 7'},
    8 : {name:'Record 8', text:'This is the text 8', options:'Anything 8'},
    9 : {name:'Record 9', text:'This is the text 9', options:'Anything 9'}
};

$(document).ready(function() {
    populateEntries();        
});

//dynamically populate the entries
function populateEntries() {
    for (entry in data){
console.log(entry);       
        $('#buttons-container').append('<a class="bt-record" href="#" onclick="showRecord(' + entry + '); return false;">' + data[entry].name + '</a>');
    }
}

//show the record
function showRecord(id) {
    //create the html
    var html = '';
    html += '<p>Name : ' + data[id].name + '</p>';
    html += '<p>Text : ' + data[id].text + '</p>';
    html += '<p>Name : ' + data[id].options + '</p>';
    $('#record-content').html(html);
    $('#record').animate({right:0}, 500);
}

function closeRecord() {
    $('#record').animate({right:-240}, 500);
}
```

In this example, I populate the records dynamically, but if you want a SEO friendly way of doing it, you can create the HTML in the page directly. Let me know if you have questions.

Comment: umm would it still work if the records where hortizally along the screen so one record takes up the entire length of the page and when its cliked is brings across the other box? and would it be hard to connect up this code to a mysql database... thanks

Comment: Yes it's possible, you need to change width in the CSS of the 'bt-record' to width:100%;. As for connecting it to a mysql database, you could always do an ajax call when the record is clicked to retrieve the record's data.

Comment: oh ok then umm what makes it a little different to what i was doing was i had php using a while loop to make all the records is it psossible to use the while looop to generate the javascript for the records or

Comment: of course. You would simply need to create the javascript with your php. echo "<script type='text/javascript'>";
    echo "var data = " . $alltherest;
    echo "</script>";

Comment: Remember this is one way of doing it out of dozens. The ajax method would also be a good choice, especially if you have 1000+ records because then your data array would be very memory consuming. It all depends on your need and knowledge with php/jquery/ajax

Comment: i am ok with my php but am still staring out on jquery and ajax but am learning as i am going...

Comment: I understand, a new language can be hard at first but jquery's learning curve is quite smooth. The ajax call would be pretty simple. You would call a php script and pass it an id. This script would then output the right HTML and when you get the answer, you would simply put it in the record's opening box.

Comment: im wondering when i scroll down the page how would i get it to follow me down the page... as i scroll down the page

Comment: change position:absolute to position:fixed in the CSS for #record

Comment: thanks heaps ive just noticed that now that i made the records go right across the screen it only will make 8 go down the page and wont make any more than that.. so basicly i cant scroll down the page to see the other records?? sorry that im not able to work thesse out myself

Comment: It's all CSS related :). Remove height = 100% to the #container. Here's an updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/dUm2j/3/

Answer (score 1):

Sure, let me show you a simple example. It is rather very easy

```
<table>
    <tr class="recordrow" id="row-1"> <!-- row-X will be the unique way to identify the row -->
       <td>...</td> <!-- The record field -->
       <td>...</td>
       ....
    </tr>
</table>

<!-- Now we create the details Div, but as reference to the `row-X` -->
<div class="details" id="details-1">
   ... More details of the records
</div>
```

then a simple *jQuery* snippet like this will get the job done:

```
$(".recordrow").click(function() {
    var divid = "details-" + $(this).attr('id').split("-")[1]; //Create the id of the div
    $("#"+divid).show().animate({ "left": '200px'}); //Bring the div from right to left with 200px padding from the screen
});
```

#### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rUcjG/1/)

Answer (score 0):

I would add a class to each individual div like this:

```
<div id="someid" class="clickable">
    your content here
    <div class="showonclick" style="visibility:hidden"> 
        The stuff to show on click here 
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){  
    $(".clickable").each(function() {
        var ref = this;
        $(ref).click(function() {
            $(ref + " .showonclick").fadeIn('slow');
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Basically this is adding a on click handler to each div with the specified class as soon as the document is ready.

I hope this helps you out.